# How to get an element of a tuple without literal strings?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

**ClickHouse** like some other **SQL DBMS** has the `Tuple` type, which elements may be accessed in query via dot-notation: `SELECT tuple(1, 2).1`. Writing queries in *Python* with `sqlalchemy`, I wonder how to get the same there without literal `ColumnClause`, because the latter forces me to compile subexpression to place it into *f-string*. I would like to write something alike `get_element(sa.func.tuple(subex1, subex2, …, subexn), attr=attr_name)`.

I tried to use classic attribute access methods but they do not work in `sqlalchemy`, like `tup.a`, `tup["a"]`.